# Picture automatic panning, ken burns effect

Tags: jquery

Would like to find a plugin that can pan in on a picture, but doing this automatically.

The picture would resize to make this animation, but clip the right and bottom. Using Jquerys built in functionality makes it choppy.

```
 jQuery('#banner').find('img').animate({
   width: 1183 + 'px',
   height: 628 + 'px'
   }, 65000, 'linear');
 });
```

This is no good.

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/mFeXC/) seems pretty smooth to me :s

Comment: Found a panning solution
[CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/)

Comment: looks like a good one ;) another alternative is [css transformations](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/mFeXC/1/), those are gpu accelerated and should be smoother..

Comment: My question was wrong, I meant panning. Tried CrossSlide but was not that good. Any other alternatives?

Comment: then update the question, and title. Describe exactly what you need help with.

Comment: Actually it should work like CrossSlide, the Ken Burns effect.